# Add date picker for WP8 in Cordova

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to call the native WP8 datepicker in a Cordova project.
Do I need a plugin for that?
The plugin should be only for WP8, for IOS and Android I want to use the native input.

I tried this one 'https://github.com/hypermurea/phonegap-wp8-datepicker-plugin' but it fails on compilation with the following error:

```
(Plugins\com.hypermurea.phonegap.wp8-datetimepicker-plugin\DateTimePickerTask.cs(83,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NavigationInTransition' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Projectos\VS\NoesisWrapper\NoesisWrapper\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\NoesisWrapper.csproj]
1>Plugins\com.hypermurea.phonegap.wp8-datetimepicker-plugin\DateTimePickerTask.cs(84,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NavigationOutTransition' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Projectos\VS\NoesisWrapper\NoesisWrapper\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\NoesisWrapper.csproj]
1>Plugins\com.hypermurea.phonegap.wp8-datetimepicker-plugin\DateTimePickerTask.cs(85,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDateTimePickerPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Projectos\VS\NoesisWrapper\NoesisWrapper\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\NoesisWrapper.csproj])
```

I'm using VS2015 v14.0.22609.0, and added the WPToolkit to the project via NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install windows phone toolkit. Please install it as mentioned in below link:
 https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit